# Split time range and interval into multiple time ranges in case of a DST time change

Tags: c#, datetime, dst, timespan

I am working on an application in C# which gets statistics data for different time ranges and then writes the data to a SQL Server table.

Right now, the application uses UTC for everything. The user simply provides a start date/time and an interval and the application will then get the data for each interval and write it to the SQL Server table. For example, if the user provides "20.10.2020 00:00" (German format) and an interval of 1 day, the application will get data for 20.10.2020 00:00, 21.10.2020 00:00, 22.10.2020 00:00 and so on.

This generally works just fine but there is a problem when a DST change happens. Because the application calculates everything in UTC, after the DST change the data will no longer be written for 00:00 but instead for one or more hours earlier or later. However, this is not the desired behavior so I need to find a solution that prevents DST changes from causing this problem.

My first idea is to split the time range containing the DST change into multiple time ranges before and after the DST change, where the one after the DST change has an offset equal to the number of hours the clock was changed by. However, I am not sure if there is a simple way to get the times where a DST change happens for a given time zone? Or am I maybe just over complicating things and should just switch to local time entirely?

The method for getting the statistics data requires me to provide a start date/time and an interval, so there I absolutely have to split this into multiple function calls to take the DST change into account.

Comment: You say your application uses UTC for everything. But then where does the issue come from? Is that your backend processing uses UTC everywhere (definitely correct) and the front end uses local? So when your user enters a time that crosses the time zone you're not sure what to do for the best?

Comment: @AdamBenson My application uses UTC for everything but the data in the SQL Server table will later be displayed in local time via a View which converts the UTC timestamps to local time.

Comment: Thanks for that. And when you say "this is not the desired behaviour" you mean your customer has said "I only want to see midnight on my UI"? You could have 1 of your data points calculated from 23 or 25 hours and make that clear on the UI. Would that work? Or make it clear that if a calc crosses the time zone it will show. There isn't really any shielding the customer from the fact that on 2 days in the year things change. Definitely do not go to local in your backend.

Comment: @AdamBenson Thanks for the response! Yeah, the customer basically wants to only see midnight on the UI like you said. I was able to fix this problem already after a few hours of work. Actually the function I used to get the statistics data is already able to calculate one of the data points for 23 or 25 hours automatically. The only problem was that for some reason when creating the time span object for this it would convert 1 day to 24 hours which would then cause the function to not take the DST change into account. I fixed this and now the function already does everything I needed to do.